# Localization: GPS won't work

Tags: android, localization, gps

I'm trying to get the location of the device so I created the class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener
```

and a method

```
private Location getLocation(Context ctx) {
    Location location = null;
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);

    for(int i=providers.size() - 1; i>=0; i--) {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(providers.get(i), 100, 1, MainActivity.this);
        location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
        if(location != null) {
            Log.i("Used provider", providers.get(i));
            break;
        }
    }

    if(location != null) {
        Log.i("Latitude", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
        Log.i("Longitude", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
        Log.i("Accuracy", String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy())+" m");
    }

    return location;
}
```

It works quite nicely but it always skips the GPS, even if I'm outside. I have to say I left all the overriden methods from the interface LocationListener empty since I don't know what I should put there.
Any idea? Do you think the code I'm using is OK? Thank you very much!

EDIT:
Thanks for the reply but there must be something wrong in my code. Through the Log I can see which provider the device is using: yesterday it was using "passive" and the position was perfect (26 m accuracy) while today it is still using "passive" but the accuracy is 2288 m which is incredibly worse! If I try to locate my position using Google Maps it is perfectly fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you trying to use GPS to determine which language (locale) to show your application in?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to locate the device (i.e. get the coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

I think it chooses the location from GSM/WiFi because it is faster than a location from GPS, try to disable WiFi or disable getting location from WiFi/GSM, and then try to locate.